# Does parking my car with 2 wheels on the sidewalk and 2 wheels on the road cause issues in the long term?

Tags: tires, wheels, damage, parking, chassis

Since there is no parking space at the place I’m renting, I have to park my car with 2 wheels on the sidewalk and 2 wheels on the road. This also includes going up and down the sidewalk with the 2 wheels on an almost daily basis.

Can this cause any damage in the long run?

Comment: Yes, it could prevent users of the sidewalk getting past.

Comment: @SolarMike I agree that this is normally the case. However, that's not a concern in this particular case because the sidewalk is extremely wide and everyone else who lives on this street and who has a car parks this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no ... it's no different than parking on a side slope. Even in your case it sounds as if the "side slope" really isn't that much of a deal. Just like parking on uneven terrain ... and ... yup, that's exactly what's going on. :o) Shouldn't be an issue at all.